# Apache Mesos Master on every node

Tags: fault-tolerance, apache-mesos

Is it good idea to launch mesos `master` and mesos `slave` together on every node?

If no, how to calc number of `master` nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Having mesos master and slave in same instance is not good practice. If your system is down then it affects your entire cluster operations

Mesos depends on zookeeper for leader election.

To launch simple mesos cluster run zookeeper and mesos master in one instance

Launch slaves in other machines pointing to mesos master.

**For HA setup**

Run zookeeper

Have 3 stand by master

Point all slaves to ZK.

If mesos master gets down ZK promotes stand by master as mesos master.